# In angular form how to get an array of Client object and use the id value as a value in a form group's member

Tags: angular

We have an API POST method called CreateEvent(obj) that takes an object. One of the properties in the object is an int ClientId
We have a GET method called GetClients() that returns the list of Client objects in the database.

In our angular reactive form's ts and html we want to be able to have a dropdown with the returned array of the GetClients. Like so: {{clnt.id}} - {{clnt.FirstName}} {{clnt.LastName}}.
How would I go about mapping the selected clnt.id value to the form's ClientId value.

You might be able to see the idea I have so far with the code below:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="clientsClone" formControlName="clientId" (change)="doSomething()">
<option *ngFor="let clnt of clientsClone"  [ngValue]="clnt.id">{{clnt.id}} - {{clnt.pointOfContact}} </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

having the [{ngModel}] in there was bad.
the code below allowed me to make it so that: 'clientsClone' is an array of objects returned from the server and the [value]="clnt.id" with the formControlName="clientId" lets me say "hey this id int is what you need for that form's value!"

code here:

```
<select formControlName="clientId" (change)="onOptionsChanged(2)">
<option *ngFor="let clnt of clientsClone" [value]="clnt.id">{{clnt.id}} - {{clnt.pointOfContact}} </option>
</select>
```